# Let $f(x+y)=2021^xf(y)+2021^yf(x)$ where $f(x)$ is continuous and $f(1)=1$. Find $f(x)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Let $f(x+y)=2021^xf(y)+2021^yf(x)$  where $f(x)$ is continuous and $f(1)=1$. Find $f(x)$
When $x=y=0$ we have $f(0)=2021^0f(0)+2021^0f(0)=2f(0)$ $\rightarrow f(0)=0$. 
When $x=0, y=y$ we have $f(y)=f(y)$ 
When $x=x, y=0$ we have $f(x)=f(x)$ 
When $x=y$ we have $f(2x)=2.2021^xf(x)$ 
Let's $x=\dfrac{x}{2}$ 
$$\begin{aligned}
f(x)&=2.2021^\frac{x}{2}f(\dfrac{x}{2}) =2^2.2021^\frac{x}{2}2021^\frac{x}{4}f(\dfrac{x}{4})\\&=...\\&=2^{n-1}.2021^{x.(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+...+\frac{1}{2^n})}f(\dfrac{x}{2^n})
\end{aligned}
$$
Take $n \to \infty $ we have $f\left( x \right) = {2^\infty }{.2021^x}.f\left( 0 \right)$. I dont have idea to solve this step. My solution is true? please help me. Many thanks to you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Divide both sides by $2021^{x+y}$ and let $$g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{2021^x}.$$

Then $$g(x+y)=?$$

Comment: $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$ so $g(x)=ax$ then $f(x)=ax.2021^x$, with $f(1)=1$ then $a=\frac{1}{2021}$. So $f(x)=\dfrac{x2021^x}{2021}$. My answer is true ? Thanks for hint.

Comment: Yes, correct. That can be rewritten as $f(x)=x2021^{x-1}.$